# Android app and memeory leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I was testing my first Android App in my physical device and when monitoring memory in Android Studio I noticed the allocated memory increased from 16 MB to 25 MB in a short period of time.

**memory monitor**
[image]

Does this mean that I have memroy leak in the app? the total memory usage for the app is around 70MB, and this number increases as you open and close the app for longer time.

Comment: just google "java garbage collection"

Comment: @lelloman I know the drop means it is automatically garbage collection. I am asking if jumping from 16 to 25+ is a sign of memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jumping from 16 to 25 is not a sign of memory leak, it's a sign that 9mb of memory have been allocated. you can see that memory drops back to 17 so at a first glance I'd say you don't have a memory leak. 
I now see your edit, 70mb doesn't mean you have a memory leak anyway, the fact that memory usage increases over time doesnt mean memory leak either. Memory leak occurs when objects that are supposed to be garbage collected are retained in memory. For example, if you see that in memory you have many instances of destroyed activities, that could very likely be a memory leak, but if you keep allocating activities because of a very big navigation stack, well that would mean you're just using a lot of memory
There are a few things you can do though:
-Setup [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) in your app, it will tell you if you there's something suspicius.

-In the memory monitor of android studio you should see an icon with a garbage truck, when you click it it will trigger a garbage collection manually, it might be useful to check how much memory the app is actually using

-In the memory monitor you should also see other 2 icons to the right of the garbage truck, the first one (with the arrow down) will show you all the objects currently allocated and their sizes, the other one will allow to start tracking all the allocation the app is making, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html?utm_source=android-studio)